# How can I get a value from my config.properties file?

Tags: java, groovy

```
    config {
     states = [ 

      [     
      requestfilepattern='request',
      responsefilepattern='response',
      xpathoperationexpression='local-name(//soap-env:Body/*[1])',
      dmurl='',
      finishedthreshold='',
      underreviewthreshold='',
      failappnumbers='',
      ignorenodes = {
        example = ["MAKE"]
      }
      ]
}
```

I am currently working on a project that was given to me which contains this code in a config.properties file. I need to get the value of the example field within ignore nodes. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a better way means that you have tried something. What have you tried to do ?

Comment: I have tried to access this via declaring this file as a properties file and trying to get this by passing in a string as my argument. for example, properties.ignorenodes.get("example"), or something similar.

Comment: This is specifically aimed at Grails 3 but some of the methods work with Grails 2, http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/posts/2016/08/31/retrieving-config-values.html

Comment: I actually figured out what my issue was, My input stream was not finding the correct file, once I mended this issue everything was working okay, Thanks for the help guys.